# Pressing button - call function in JS

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, call

I would like to ask why I am getting those 2 errors. Please note that I have zero control on the code of the html which the compiler react with

*Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null*

*Uncaught: ReferenceError: createdButton is not defined*

Answer (score 0):

These errors are pretty straightforward. The first one is telling you that there is no element with the id of `btn` in your HTML, hence why it's returning null.

For the second one I don't see where you're calling `createdButton`, but it's telling you it isn't defined anywhere. If I had to take a guess, either you're calling `createdButton` before you define it or there's not a variable named `createdButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. You have no element with id of "btn", try adding the id to the button you want to listen the onclick event.
2. I wonder why this error is happening: *Uncaught: ReferenceError: createdButton is not defined*. Because, there are no words about `createdButton`. Can you give us the full code?